# this js script , accept only integer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im having a problem with this code , the select statement returns value only when the parameter is integer ... look at the code ..my problem is when the value of the dropdown ( select ) is an integer , the select statement works fine , otherwise it returns nothing .

```
    <script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


    <body>


                    <form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(users.value)">
<option value="">choose a subject</option>
<option value="223">English</option>
<option value="2">ar</option>
<option value="161">علوم عامة</option>
<option value="ar">عربي</option>
</select>

<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Course info will be listed here.</b></div>


                               </p>
                               <p>&nbsp; </p>
    <div class="clear"></div></div></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>    
</form>
</body>


//---------------and the getuser.php is

    <?php
require_once("_gradeviewr.php");
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','evang_www');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"evang_www");
$sql="SELECT * FROM uploaded WHERE subject = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

<th>subject</th>
<th>Date from</th>
<th>Date To</th>
<th>filename</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['datefrom'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['dateto'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['filename'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<select name="users" id="urselectboxId">
```

Script

```
$('#urselectboxId').on('change',function(){
var str=$(this).val();
if (str=="")
  {
  $("txtHint").text("");
  return;
  }
else
  {
    $.ajax({
        url:"getuser.php",
        type:"get",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {q:str},
        success:function(data){
            // codes....
        }
     });
  }

});
```

Comment: nothing happened , dreamweaver gave me an error on this : $('#urselectboxId').on('change'function()

Comment: @user3526074 you have jquery in library? check with about code again

Comment: i dont know where to add the libray ,, im just new at jquery .

Comment: add jquery library js in `<head>` block and add this code in `$(document).ready(function(){ ..above function..});`

Comment: it shoul be `$('#urselectboxId').on('change',function()`

Comment: same problem :( , error on this : $('#urselectboxId').on('change'function()

Comment: @user3526074 after change use `,`

Comment: error now on this >> xmlhttp.send();
}); <<<<<<<  the end of the code .

Comment: @user3526074 check with above one and updae me

Comment: still having the problem